# web2py - Controller function isn't called when using anchor tag callback

Tags: python, web2py

When a user visits a magazine page, a button should appear that will allow the currently logged in user to subscribe to a particular magazine if that user is already logged in. The button should not be visible to an anonymous user.

I have gotten the button to show up when the user has logged in, but clicking on the button doesn't call my controller function.

If this is the controller function:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def subscribe():
    mag_id = request.args(0, cast=int)
    db.subscribe.insert(magazine=mag_id, subscriber=auth.user.id)
```

And this is the part of the views:

```
<div>
    {{=magazine.title}}
    {{=magazine.description}}
</div>

<div>
{{ if auth.is_logged_in():}}
    {{=A('subscribe', _class="btn_subscribe", callback=URL("subscribe", args=magazine.id))}}
{{pass}}
</div>
```

The `<a>` button shows up as this:

```
<a href="#null" onclick="ajax('/myapp/default/subscribe/3',[],'me');return false">subscribe</a>
```

And the controller function is never called, and the user is never subscribed.

Comment: Your `A()` helper generates the following HTML: `<a class="btn_subscribe" href="#null" onclick="ajax(&#x27;/test/default/subscribe/3&#x27;,[],&#x27;&
#x27;);return false">subscribe</a>`. Where does the 'me' come from in your output above? Anyway, are you sure web2py.js is loaded?

Comment: @Anthony I'm not sure where 'me' is coming from. It seems to be generated automatically by web2py. You were right about the web2py.js being missing. I added that and the controller is now being called. Can you make an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: @Anthony Is there a way to refresh the page after the subscribe button is clicked? That way the anchor button text will change to 'You are subscribed' to indicate to the user that the user is now subscribed? Currently I have to refresh the entire page manually to see the change.

Comment: how do I include another span into A()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony had suggested, adding the web2py.js was the solution.