# web2py: link to execute a function without navigating to a different page (callback?)

Tags: python, ajax, web-applications, web2py

Using web2py (2.8.2-stable+timestamp.2013.11.28.13.54.07), how do I construct a link in a View that executes a function, but does not navigate away from the current page?

The [web2py OnLine book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Built-in-helpers) states that, for a call to the built-in helper A() used in a View: 'Instead of _href you can pass the URL using the callback argument . . . the effect of pressing the link will be an ajax call to "myaction" instead of a redirection'. (My understanding of 'redirection' is to navigate the browser to a different page). However, the web2py View source (inside a loop):

```
{{=A('why does this callback redirect?', callback=URL('PlayAnAlbum2', vars = dict(album_folder = album_folder, type = 'artists')))}}
```

does execute the desired function, but also redirects to either the View of the named function, or a page consisting of 'None' if the function doesn't return anything.

I would like a click on the link to only execute a function, and not load a different View (so no view is required and I expect nothing need be returned by the function except maybe whether the function encountered any errors). An example of the source that is generated is as follows:

```
<a data-w2p_disable_with="default" data-w2p_method="POST" href="/AlbumBrowser/default/PlayAnAlbum2?album_folder=Jaga+Jazzist%2F2003+The+Stix&amp;type=artists" id="10aa76bd-c4bf-4701-a0da-1ebfed7847cc">why does this callback redirect?</a>
```

But I had expected something like the following (I made this up loosely based on code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307350/web2py-controller-function-isnt-called-when-using-anchor-tag-callback) so may not make sense):

```
<a href="#null" onclick="ajax('/AlbumBrowser/default/PlayAnAlbum2',['album_folder','type'],None);return false">why does this callback redirect?</a>
```

I can confirm `{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}` is in the layout head and `<script src="/AlbumBrowser/static/js/web2py.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is in the generated page source.

Comment: Have you upgraded web2py since creating this application? If so, it is possible your web2py.js file is out of date. Try updating it to the latest version. The generated HTML source you observe is correct and should work (the code in web2py.js identifies links with the data-w2p_method attribute and converts them to Ajax calls).

Comment: I upgraded from 2.7.4 to 2.8.2. Because this application was based on the 'welcome' I also tried to update files within this application that may need it (js and css in static, web2py_ajax.html and generic.* in views). The link still redirects to a page containing text 'None' with URL corresponding to View of called function.

Answer (score 1):

As is stated in the question and [the web2py book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Built-in-helpers), use `callback=URL()` instead of `_href=URL()` within `A()`.

This definitely works in web2py 2.8.2.

Comment: Thanks to Anthony. This was not working for me in 2.7.2, but did work after upgrading . . . but not immediately(!) I answered my own question to confirm the issue is not with web2py and that the described code was the correct approach. If this is bad etiquette let me know and I'll remove the Answer. I had used an external editor, so my advice for misbehaving applications is to (i) update web2py (obviously and before posting a question!) (ii) rebuild the application via the 'create new application' button in the web2py's admin facility and pasting code in to web2py's IDE.

Comment: in case my function returns SCRIPT("alert('some random text)") how can I prevent redirection after clicking Ok button in alert window?